# Printing a blank space beforehand if a number is 1 digit

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a list of numbers that change depending on user input. As an example let's say my list is `[26, 13, 51, 46, 9, 15]`. I'm using `print(" ".join(str(e) for e in mylist))` to print them without commas and brackets and with a space in between. What I want to do is print 2 spaces before a number if it's one-digit/below 10. So the output I'd want with the example I gave would be `26 13 51 46  9 15`. How can I do this?

Comment: Replace `str(e)` with `f"{e:2d}"` (if on Python older then 3.6: `"{:2d}".format(e)`)

Comment: @OndrejK. This works really well but I'm a complicated man, and I don't like the way curly brackets look! :) Thanks a bunch for your suggestion though!

Comment: Like it or not, the future is curly... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use rjust:

```
'hi'.rjust(3)
' hi'

print(' '.join(str(e).rjust(2) for e in mylist))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Short and simple. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use string formatting:

```
print(" ".join("{:2d}".format(e) for e in mylist))
```

Also, `" ".join` can be replaced by unpacking due to the default `sep=' '` of the `print` function:

```
print(*("{:2d}".format(e) for e in mylist))
```

Comment: This works well! What I needed was something like @Tdaw's solution, but yours is a good alternative. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Could this be what you're looking for?

```
mylist = [26, 13, 51, 46, 9, 15]
for number in mylist:
    if len(str(number)) == 1:
        print(f" {number}")
    else: print(str(number))
```

Comment: Yep this is what I needed! But silly me doesn't like putting curly brackets, so the solution I used was @Tdaw 's suggestion. This is good too though! Thanks a lot. :)